# Hibernate 3 Maven Plugin -> remove "Generated by Hibernate Tools"

Tags: maven, hibernate-tools, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I am Using the hibernate 3 Maven Plugin Version 2.2 to create my Entities of the database. This works great, but i have one problem.
My entities contain the Comment : // Generated 07.10.2015 12:46:10 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.2.GA

Is there any way to configure the maven plugin to not put the comment in my generated entities?

I like to add them to git when i regenerated them. But in that case the entities change on every generate-sources goal cause the date in the "generated by" comment changes.

I searched alot, but i didnt find any working solution.
Some wrote that it is possible to use a custom .ftl file to define to generated entities. but in my case this ftl file i added wasnt used by the maven plugin.

thx alot ;)

Comment: FYI, it is not a good idea to version control generated code for this particular reason. It should be generated under `target` and stay there. I'm not sure it is possible to suppress that message.

Comment: @Tunaki In principle you are right, but it can take very long time to generate even if nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Override the templates distributed by hibernate-tools.
Copy them to `/src/main/templates` and configure them in maven like `<templatepath>src/main/tempates</templatepath>`.

I actually generate like you and i come to a different problem: Sometimes the fields, getters and setters shuffle its order in the java-files. That makes it hard to compare. In eclipse you could order the fields and getters in the correct order before commit. Maybe there is a way to do it using the maven-lifecycle.